# Vue-gtag @legacy query not returning client id

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, gtag.js

As I'm using Vue2, I insalled vue-gtag@legacy as it's the version compatible with version 2 of VueJS.

main.ts plugin setup:

```
import VueGtagPlugin from "vue-gtag";
Vue.use(VueGtagPlugin, {
  config: { id: "G-MY-MEASUREMEND-ID" }
});
```

The plugin is loaded correctly - this is the console.log of this.$gtag:

```
{query: ƒ, config: ƒ, optOut: ƒ, optIn: ƒ, pageview: ƒ, …}
config: ƒ ()
customMap: ƒ (map)
event: ƒ (name)
exception: ƒ ()
linker: ƒ (params)
optIn: ƒ ()
optOut: ƒ ()
pageview: ƒ (param)
purchase: ƒ (params)
query: ƒ ()
refund: ƒ ()
screenview: ƒ (param)
set: ƒ ()
time: ƒ (params)
```

However if I try to access client_id (which is my main goal), the callback prints nothing - it seems it doesn't even go inside the callback:

```
this.$gtag.query("get", "G-MY-MEASUREMEND-ID", "client_id", clientID => {
   console.log("CID", clientID);
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try entering this in ***nuxt.config.ts***

> ```
> {
>   src: '~/plugins/main.ts',
>   // if you use ssr
>   ssr: true
>   // if you use csr
>   mode: 'client'
>   // chooise one
> }
> ```

source : https://www.carlcassar.com/articles/add-google-analytics-to-a-nuxt-js-app

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to use the `get` method in `vue-gtag`; I think `query` method is not prepared for that:
https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag/issues/251

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).